# Algorithm for finding best top-scoring combinations

Tags: algorithm, sorting

I am looking for an algorithm to identify combinations of game outcomes that maximize total points. The rules for the combinations
are as follows:

- There are a total of N games
- Each game has 3 possible outcomes (win, lose, or draw)
- Each outcome has positive or negative score

Find the top outcome combinations of size N in order to maximize the total score

For example, with N = 2:

```
Game 1, Outcome 1 = +3 points
Game 1, Outcome 2 = -1 points
Game 1, Outcome 3 = -3 points

Game 2, Outcome 1 = -3 points
Game 2, Outcome 2 = +1 points
Game 2, Outcome 3 = +3 points
```

With these 2 games and point values for each possible outcome, here is the ordered list of combinations I would expect to see. Note that combinations 4, 5, and 6 are ties so they could have been in any order here.

```
Combination 1 = (Game 1, Outcome 1) + (Game 2, Outcome 3) -> Total +6 points
Combination 2 = (Game 1, Outcome 1) + (Game 2, Outcome 2) -> Total +4 points
Combination 3 = (Game 1, Outcome 2) + (Game 2, Outcome 3) -> Total +2 points
Combination 4 = (Game 1, Outcome 1) + (Game 2, Outcome 1) -> Total  0 points
Combination 5 = (Game 1, Outcome 2) + (Game 2, Outcome 2) -> Total  0 points
Combination 6 = (Game 1, Outcome 3) + (Game 2, Outcome 3) -> Total  0 points
Combination 7 = (Game 1, Outcome 3) + (Game 2, Outcome 2) -> Total -2 points
Combination 8 = (Game 1, Outcome 2) + (Game 2, Outcome 1) -> Total -4 points
Combination 9 = (Game 1, Outcome 3) + (Game 2, Outcome 1) -> Total -6 points
```

I can compute these ordered combinations by brute force for small values of N, but given that there are a total of 3^N combinations and that N can be as large as 128, I don't expect brute force to work for very long. So, I am looking for a way to identify the first M combinations, where M << the total number (3^N) of combinations.

I've spent quite a bit of time trying to come up with an algorithmic way to pick these combinations but I'm coming up short. I'd appreciate any suggestions that point me in the right direction.

Thanks

Comment: How about considering just the top scoring outcomes for each game?

Comment: @user2963623 That's good enough for M <= 1 :):):)

Comment: I am not sure, but I don't think you can do better than brute force since there's a total of 3^N combinations, and if you want to sort them, that means that you'll have to compute them all before sorting. So you will at least have to go through 3^N operations first.

Comment: @Tim Dean Is there a bound on maximum and minimum value of the outcome of each game? If there is then it might be possible to avoid some computations once it becomes clear that they cannot give a better score than a current best score. Also, you might be able to avoid recomputing the sum of outcomes up to say K by caching them and use them to compute the scores for outcomes > K, i.e. dynamic programming. But if the number of combinations is huge (depending on your N) then the memory needed for the cache makes it unfeasible.

Comment: @Tim Dean I forgot to add, the bound checking and elimination approach that I suggested is called the "branch and bound" method in combinatorial optimization. You can check it out if it helps. Looking up the literature on combinatorial optimization or check out Steven Skiena's Algorithm Design Manual on related combinatorial problems might help. Although in theory this seems like a very difficult problem but the whole field of combinatorial optimization is basically created to tackle them to give decent runtime in practice under certain conditions that might be exploitable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can generate `M` combinations iteratively using a [*Priority Queue*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Priority_queue). First, you need to make a data structure that represents a single combination, along with a function to compute its score. For example, you could use an array of `N` small integers representing the number of the outcome. Use the score function to order the combinations inside the queue.

You will also need a way to quickly identify that you have seen a particular combination. For that your combination representation needs to have a hash function. Make a hash set of the combinations that you have explored.

It is trivial to compute the top combination: you can do it by grabbing the highest-value outcome for each of the `N` games. Add this combination to the priority queue, then run the following loop:

- Dequeue the next best combination, and add it to the list of results.
- If the length of the result list is `M`, you are done
- Otherwise, go through the current combination, and produce up to `2N` "derived" combinations from it
- Each derived combination differs from the current combination in a single game outcome
- Flip the outcome of each game from the best to the second best, then to the worst.
- Check the combination with "flipped" outcomes against the hash set of the combinations you have explored
- If this is a new combination, add it to the hash set and also to the priority queue
- When you are done with the derived combinations, trim the queue down to `M-res` items, where `res` is the number of items on the results list
- Continue to the next iteration.

Comment: Thanks for the ideas @dasblinkenlight. I am a little confused about your explanation though. You refer to the priority queue and the list of results in this algorithm. I assume those are different data structures, correct? If so, where in this algorithm to combinations get added to the result list?

Comment: @TimDean Yes, the queue and the list of results are different. An item is added to the result after being dequeued at step 1.

Comment: Thanks @dasblinkenlight: I somehow missed that point in my first read-through. I think I see how this would work now. One more question though: What is the purpose of the step to trim down the queue at the end of each iteration? Is it just to keep the priority queue from being longer than it really needs to be? It seems like that step could be skipped and I'd still get the same result. Is that true?

Comment: @TimDean Correct, you can skip the trimming step. However, since storing a combination may require significant amount of memory, trimming the queue may be desirable. If you use a double-ended priority queue, the trimming step would be very easy to implement.